# Kafka Stream from JSON to Avro

Tags: json, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I try to use Kafka Stream to convert a topic with String/JSON messages to another topic as Avro messages.

Stream main method:

```
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class); 

    final KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();


    final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();

    builder.stream(stringSerde, stringSerde, "testin")
            .mapValues(value -> AvroUtil.transform(value))
            .to("testout");

    final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, streamsConfiguration);
    streams.start();
```

Transformation:

```
public static GenericRecord transform(Object value) {

    // ... parse string/json and generate Avro object

    String userSchema = "{\"type\":\"record\"," +
            "\"name\":\"myrecord\"," +
            "\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"f1\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}";
    Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
    Schema schema = parser.parse(userSchema);
    GenericRecord avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
    avroRecord.put("f1", "value1");

    return avroRecord;
}
```

And get an exception like this:

```
Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty.access()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty$Access;
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyAccess(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:229)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder$9.withMember(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:545)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder$9.withMember(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:542)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.fromMemberAnnotationsExcept(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:996)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.findAccess(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:542)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.removeNonVisible(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:623)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._removeUnwantedAccessor(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:697)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:298)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getJsonValueMethod(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:169)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findJsonValueMethod(BasicBeanDescription.java:222)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerByAnnotations(BasicSerializerFactory.java:355)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:210)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:153)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1203)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1157)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:481)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:679)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:107)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3559)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2927)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.entities.requests.RegisterSchemaRequest.toJson(RegisterSchemaRequest.java:76)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:232)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:224)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:219)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:58)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:90)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:72)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:54)
```

Is this the right approach? I'm new to Kafka Streams and Avro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just the jackson dependencies were missing:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now it works

Comment: how fast can we convert json to avro. so basically we pickup from one topic convert the file and then put it back to the diff topic . what is the latency here?