# Kafka Stream to consume JSON and Produce Avro

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

As i am new to Kafka and Avro. Please provide me Git Hub Url if any from where i can check code and all the configuration that need to be done .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a search service. Just use your most favorite search engine... Btw: https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/changing-serialization-format/ksql.html

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303730/kafka-stream-from-json-to-avro) is the solution you're looking for. For more details about what and how of the code, please refer to kafka stream [tutorial](https://kafka.apache.org/25/documentation/streams/tutorial), specifically `Run Demo App` and `Tutorial: Write App` sections of tutorial should come in handy.
`Run Demo App` section will guide you basic kafka setup and you can skip executing demo app if you want. 
 `Tutorial: Write App` section will guide you through creating a java kstream sample app as per your need. After you setup maven project through this section, there you will find sample code as well.